# shuffle algorithm: department shuffle for dinner

Tags: algorithm

In order to enlarge communication, the company decides to have departments mixed for dinner. Suppose each table is designed to allow 10 people for dinner, but adding another people is also ok. Therefore if staffs number N % 10 is less than 6, then the N % 10 people should place into other 10 people sited table.

Suppose there are 20 departments, each departments has 10~30 people. How would you arrange the dinner randomly so that people inside the same department has the least chance to be in the same table, and the property of every two departments has about the same chance to meet in the table?

*My implementation is randomly put 10 people a table first. And then leave unique one for each department in each table, and take others out and put in a array. The the array is shuffled randomly and put back to the tables. Do this until the cost function F never decrease, while F is defined as sum of the number people of the same department shown in the same table.*

Comment: Your problem definition is incomplete -- you have to define what an acceptable solution is.

Comment: @AlexD Thank you, i have modified this question to be more precisely.

Comment: Your last edit said the people have to be assigned "randomly". This makes the problem meaningless. As soon as you do anything to bias the assignments to make it less likely that people will end up with those from the same department, it's not "random" any more.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand everything, this problem seems completely trivial. Precalculate the number of tables you will need (using the criteria you gave, based on `N%10`). Start with the largest department, and start assigning people from the department one per table. If you reach the last table, go back to the first one and continue assigning one person per table. When all the people in the department are assigned, go to the 2nd largest department, and so on. If you reach a table which is full, skip over it.

If the number of people in the largest department is less than the number of tables, your chances of having people inside the same department at the same table is 0.